# why iframe can't be set onload in IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload-event

I try the following code to listen the iframe onload event in IE8

```
            aliJob.init(data)
            aliJob.openIframe()
            alert(aliJob.ifr)
            if(aliJob.ifr.attachEvent){
                aliJob.ifr.attachEvent('onload',function(){


                    alert("before init")

                    aliJob.ifr.contentWindow.DefaultjobList.jsonInit()


                    aliJob.ifr.contentWindow.document.getElementById("markText").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].onclick=aliJob.closeIframe

                })
            }
            else{
                aliJob.ifr.onload=function(){

                    //some other code


            }
```

the `aliJob.ifr` obj is reachable as it can be alert in IE8

However,both of the way can't listener to the iframe onload,

other broswer is fine

Can someone get some ideas of it?

Comment: `aliJob.openIframe()` is `document.body.appendChild(aliJob.ifr)`